# Why all LI expend at maximum width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT**: JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mHWqX/

What it do:

[image]

How can I avoid every LI to follow the same width / padding ? I want something similar to this in a hover:

```
||||||||||
|||||||||| Regular
||||||||||
||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||| Hover
||||||||||||||||||||
||||||||||
|||||||||| Regular
||||||||||
||||||||||
|||||||||| Regular
||||||||||
||||||||||
|||||||||| Regular
||||||||||
```

thanks

Comment: please add your markup.  Please set up a demo of this at jsfiddle.  That will make it a lot easier for us to help, thanks

Comment: @EliGassert Thanks for your answer. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mHWqX/

Comment: Animating `left` instead of `padding-left` makes the element slide, rather than grow, right, which I assume is not the effect you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated/working version:  http://jsfiddle.net/mHWqX/2/

The solution is pretty simple: set your style on your anchor instead of your li.  This will cause all lis to grow in width still, but since the style is on the `a`, only the 'active' anchor will grow.

Comment: I would also recommend only saving the padding left once.  If you mouseover/out/over quickly it'll "remember" the intermediate left (as it is animating back to the starting point) and then it's "stuck."  So only set the data for padding left if it was not previously set.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. However, how can I set the height of the LI to be 100% ? They stack over each other by few pixels.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was a style choice ;) didn't notice that.  See the new updated version in my answer.  It sets the anchor to inline-block.

Comment: Nahh ! Thanks you, I fixed others bug I had and with your both solutions it's working like a charm !! Thanks !!